# Sub domain cookies are not deleting after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, http-headers

I have hosted my application in demo.foo.com (subdomain),

When I tried to log in with another user in the same browser after logout, HTTP request headers retain the old user details which are saved in Cookies request headers.

This works fine when the user closes the browser.

In Logout method I am calling ClearCookies() method,

```
   private void ClearCookies()
   {
        try
        {
            string[] TWCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
            foreach (string cookie in TWCookies)
            {
                LogMessage($"=======Cookie Name ========> {cookie}"); // here i can see cookies name and values are coming properly 
                HttpCookie cookieObj = new HttpCookie(cookie);
                cookieObj.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                cookieObj.Domain = ".foo.com"; 
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookieObj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError($"Error while deleting Cookies  {ex.Message} === 
            {ex.InnerException}");
        }
   }
```

When I click on the logout button it is showing HTTP 500 internal server error.

[image]

Comment: Some cookies are session based, some are persistent. Closing the browser will remove session based cookies, but not persistent ones. Your server side code can remove any cookie by name if you know what it is called, you might just be able to clear them all - you can only delete cookies that you control.

Comment: @IanRobertson I can see in my console, cookies are getting expire . I have attached the image. after setting expire, Its showing http 500 internal server error

Comment: Is the ClearCookies() method causing an exception? Why do you get an 500 error?

Comment: ClearCookies() method is not causing any exception